# What is the best way to name a table column when there are multiple of similar items?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, oracle, mariadb

I am trying to create a table but thought what would be the best way to name the columns.

I read some articles about database table naming conventions and saw that:

Instead of **supporterOne** or **supporterone**, a better way is **supporter_one**.

My question is which is the more appropriate name between these two?

supporter_one 
supporter_two 
supporter_three

Or

supporter_1 
supporter_2 
supporter_3

Or maybe it does not matter and I can use whatever I want?

Comment: If this is at all representative of the data you're looking to store then you're on the wrong track. You should create a separate table to hold your supporter details and link them back to the master table with an ID column and a foreign key constraint

Comment: Don't create multiple columns, create a proper one-to-many relationship

Comment: Oh I am creating two tables: Contract and Supporter table (list of supporter to choose from). And each contract can have up to three supporters. So I was curious what would be the best way to name those multiple supporter column in Contract table...!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this format as it will be easy if you are going to dynamically read or write data in a selected column based on some scenarios

```
supporter_1
supporter_2
supporter_3
```